# obfuscate default java packages and classes names using proguard

Tags: java, proguard

i have an application written in java, and i am using proguard to obfuscate it and its working very well, i mean the classes and members (data and functions) are renamed to a, ax, xy, z etc.

but when i decompile it using `jd-gui-1.2.0.jar` i found that all the default java packages and classes are visible for readers ex:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

and also the classes and functions name are visible to readers ex:

```
try
{
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  this.ab = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.db");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException|SQLException localClassNotFoundException)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Database Not Found", "Exception Occured", 0);
}
```

i am not talking about the string encrytion but the classes and functions name that are in default java packages ex: `java.sql.Connection` and `DriverManager.getConnection("")`

i am wondering how can i hide or rename all this default classes and functions names using proguard, at this point i can only thing that it could be there somewhere in proguard by mapping their names or any other way..

any help or suggestion would be a great help..

Comment: How is it supposed to find functions or classes in the default/3rd party java packages if it doesn't directly refer to them in your jar?

Comment: You can only do so much to obfuscate a binary.  Even if there was some mechanism for indirectly referring to default/3rd party stuff, even someone barely capable of reverse engineering could reconstruct the original calls with very little work.

Comment: @Brian Vandenberg i think proguard is enough to secure my code atleast from normal developers, but i am just thinking if it could be possible to hide java packages, classes or methods too by the way of mapping or any other way to make it more difficult to understand what my code is about...

Comment: Obfuscation can only be used on things you control.  Supposing a feature existed in proguard to do what you want, it would end up being a lookup table.  `XYZ` would map to `JOptionPane`, etc.  Anyone with enough skill to write a reverse engineering tool would have absolutely no problem figuring out how you do the lookup table and undo that obfuscation.

Comment: If someone has the skill to understand your code after the simplistic obfuscation you've already done, you're spinning your wheels for no benefit.  In the video game or app markets, even the very best copy protection schemes have historically lasted at most 3-4 months before they get cracked.

Comment: thanks for the info, i know that even after doing this i can not make sure that my code is secure but i would like to make it more difficult for people using `jd-gui-1.2.0.jar` or other tools like java decompiler to do reverse engineering

Comment: To exacerbate the problem further, pre-packaged protection schemes tend to make it easier for crackers because once cracked it's a simple matter to crack anything else protected with that tool.

Comment: is there a way to do it.. if yes, then please guide me, i will do the rest.

Comment: thanks for the great info and for your important time, while i am happy with proguard but thinking that i could make it more difficult or time consuming process for people doing reverse engineering..

Comment: @BrianVandenberg You better write answer instead of tens of comments. You can get some +1 :D

Comment: @Aleksandar Since I was more or less trying to prove a negative, I was more leery of  stating it as my answer; however, I changed my mind after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

When you get right down to it, code obfuscation is a form of [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).  In well written code that's more or less self documenting, names of classes/methods/functions can tell you exactly what a piece of code is doing.  Obfuscating the code in light of that is immensely helpful for keeping out less determined / knowledgeable people.

As one of my projects for teaching myself reverse engineering I wanted to find out the answer to this question: can you hit a bomb on the first click in [windows xp] minesweeper.  All I had to go off of is my knowledge of assembly, winapi, etc.  As I examined the disassembly I was able to figure out what many of the functions were doing and give them a name that was meaningful to me.  I eventually found the memory being used for the board and was able to reliably determine that the layout of the board wasn't chosen until after the 1st click; the code for generating the board layout always ensured a non-bomb was in the clicked square.

While method names & whatnot were obscured by only having addresses (that I gave meaningful names to), there's not a lot they could do to hide system/winapi/library calls.  There are a lot of creative tricks for doing just that, but they all boil down to obscure ways to do a lookup table.  Anyone with enough skill to write a tool like jd-gui-1.2.0.jar, or capable of modifying its source for their own purposes, won't have a problem figuring out any scheme you use for doing the lookup.

A common technique used for analyzing viruses that use some form of encryption/compression is to identify the code used to unpack the executable code and use that directly instead of rolling your own.  After all, why go through the effort of writing your own when the code you need is right there?

My point: although it's technically possible to do what you want I'm of the personal opinion that it's not worth your time.

Comment: thanks for the answer Sir, but i actually want to do that at least for my two classes that hold the all logic of my application.., i know even though my codes are not safe from the people doing reverse engineering :( , but at least it will not be easy for other people who are not good in doing so..